# Why does open(True, 'w') print the text like sys.stdout.write?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
with open(True, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello')
```

Why does this code print the text `Hello` instead of raise an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [built-in function documentation on `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> `open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1...`
>   *file* is either a string or bytes object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped

That "integer file descriptor" is further described in the [`os` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations):

> For example, standard input is usually file descriptor 0, standard output is 1, and standard error is 2. Further files opened by a process will then be assigned 3, 4, 5, and so forth.

Since booleans are an `int` subclass, `False` can be used interchangeably with `0` and `True` with `1`. Therefore, opening a file descriptor of `True` is the same as opening a file descriptor of `1`, which will select standard output.

Comment: So what about `0`? :)

Comment: And does it mean that when you open a file, it will be `3`, `4`, `5`, etc. ?

Comment: As it says in the second quote block, `0` is standard input, and sequential integers will be assigned as more files are opened.

Comment: @KevinGuan,  unless you have file descriptors open that have a fileno of 3, 4 or 5 it obviously won't work. It only works for 0, 1 or 2  because they are stdin, stdout and stderr which are open file descriptors.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, TigerhawkT3 Understand now, thanks :)